# Cannot get facebook.php to work on shared windows host

Tags: php, windows, facebook, pear

i get the error "Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/FB/facebook.php' (include_path='.;C:\PHP5\PEAR')"

I don't have access to the php.ini

PHP Version 5.2.17

include_path    .;C:\PHP5\PEAR

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows

Loaded Configuration File   C:\PHP5\php.ini

I've tried the other exmaples on here none are working since i don't have access to the php.ini

Any advice?

Comment: `/FB/facebook.php` refers to the root of your filesystem, not the document root of your site.

Comment: So i have to include it at E:\HostingSpaces\wwwroot\FB\
rather than \FB\
?

Comment: so then it'd be `require('e:/hostingspaces/wwwroot/fb/facebook.php')`.

Answer (score 0):

Marc B solved this.

when you include the facebook file in an other folder, you would have to specify the full include path.

eg c:\mysite\myfacebookapp\facebook.php

rather than "\myfacebookapp\facebook.php